# Google Billing Library - Access subscription on multiple devices

Tags: java, android, google-play, in-app-subscription, play-billing-library

I'm new to the implementation of Google's Billing library and using this system to make subscriptions inside my app. My question is I created a subscription in one device and i would like to access this subscription on another device. Is there any such facility available in Google billing library system to use the subscription in multiple devices?

For example: In iOS there is a Cloud concept so that subscription created on one device can be accessed on another device.

If so can you please suggest on how it can be implemented?

Comment: It all depends on how your application manages it. A subscription purchased through google services is simply tied to a users google account, not to a device, so there is nothing stopping you from using it on multiple devices provided they are on the same account? If you want it to work on multiple accounts then you need to implement your own subscription service.

Comment: Can you please provide me the link or code regarding the process of using the subscription on multiple devices that is using the same account ?

Comment: See here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate you simply need to check that the user/account has an active subscription.

Comment: Are you talking about calling BillingClient.queryPurchasesAsync() from our app in OnResume() and OnCreate() methods if we try to access the subscription on another device?